# Android: App to download files not working (only worked once)

Tags: java, android

I am making an app that downloads files to the internal storage. It worked for the first time now the files doesn't show up anymore despite getting the correct message. What seems to be the problem?

I have tried it in both emulator and my phone (kitkat)

here is my code

```
new DownloadJSON().execute();

        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {

                String memo_filename = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_service)).getText().toString();
                download_path = "http://www.sunshine-ems.balay-indang.com/attachments/memo/"+memo_filename+".docx";
                final String sd_path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
                //final String sd_path =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                dest_file_path = sd_path+"/Download/"+memo_filename+".docx";
                  dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Memo.this, "", "Downloading file...", true);
                     new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() { 
                                 //Log.d("Download Path", sd_path+""+dest_file_path+" "+download_path);
                                 downloadFile(download_path, dest_file_path);

                            }
                          }).start();    
            }
        });
    }

    //download file
    public void downloadFile(String download_path, String dest_file_path) {
        try {
            URL u = new URL(download_path);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

            File f = new File(dest_file_path);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            fos.close();
            stream.close();
            hideProgressIndicator();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            hideProgressIndicator();
            return; 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            hideProgressIndicator();
            return; 
        }

  }

  void hideProgressIndicator(){
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              dialog.dismiss();
              Toast.makeText(Memo.this,"Download Complete. Check SD Card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      });  
  }
```

Comment: Any error, Exception which helped us to find the cause...??

Comment: no error shows up it just tells me the download is done even though i cant find the file

Comment: Please debug the code. because you also call hideProgressIndicator() from catch() block.

Comment: I think you need to check whether file is exists or not then you can start download new file. Because if filename with same name is exists then it will cause an exception. So please check it first.

Comment: That's what you get when all your exception handling code does is swallowing the exception. Put handleProgressIndicator in finally and remove the catch-clauses in downloadFile for starters.